# Backbone.view.extend : How to declare events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a looking at some javascript code which uses Backbone library.

```
var parent = Backbone.view.extend({
events: {
        'click .trolley-total button': 'validateAndconfirm',
    },
})
```

What is the meaning of the **"click .trolley-total button"** line here.

Does it mean that any section(like div) which have **class="trolley-total"**, 
so if any button in that section is clicked than execute **validateAndconfirm** action.

If yes

Then there can be many buttons into the section, will it be a good practice to declare like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on how that event is handled, the first word is the event name to listen to and everything else is an optional filter for the select has the listener. That event declaration gets turned into something similar to

`parent.$el.on("click", ".trolley-total button", parent.validateAndConfirm);`

with some binding on the callback.

When run, any button inside any element with a class of `trolley-total` will fire when clicked, no limit.

As for good practice, it depends on the complexity and layout of the rest of the view. Generally using a class selector is not preferable. If you only have one button, maybe add an id and to it directly, much faster.

Comment: Events are bound to the `$el` element passed to the view, so any event listeners will only listen for events local to the view. See [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-127)